# Newest XCode doesn't compile closure initialization for UIView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I've added handful extension to `UIView` for closure initialization:

```
protocol ClosureInitialization: UIView {
    associatedtype View = Self

    init(_ configurationClosure: (View) -> ())
}

extension ClosureInitialization {

    init(_ configurationClosure: (Self) -> ()) {
        self.init(frame: .zero)
        configurationClosure(self)
    }
}

extension UIView : ClosureInitialization {}
```

Thanks to it, I can initialize views more easily, e.g.:

```
private lazy var myLabel = UILabel {
    $0.text = "Label"
    $0.textColor = .myTextColor
    $0.font = .myFont
}
```

After upgrading to XCode 13.3 / 13.3.1, it stopped compiling. The only error message I get is: `error: Illegal instruction: 4`. What's more, using XCode 13.2.1 everything compiles without an error.

Comment: Did you clean build folder ?

Comment: Yes, I tried deleting derived data too.

Comment: Did you check in the compiler output ?

Comment: "more easily". You are making your code undeadable for another programmer.
If the compiler crashes, it's always a bug and you should report it.

Comment: @PtitXav yes I did, but I didn't find any hints on what's causing the issue.

Comment: @Sulthan could you please clarify what do you mean by `You are making your code undeadable for another programmer`?

Comment: @Nominalista You are introducing a syntax feature that looks like something that is native but it is not really native. You are also adding an initializer to all views which can easily collide with other initializers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like Xcode doesn't like circular inheritance here: `ClosureInitialization` is inherited from `UIView` and `UIView` declares `ClosureInitialization`.

You can write it like this instead:

```
protocol ClosureInitialization {
    associatedtype View = Self

    init(_ configurationClosure: (View) -> ())
}

extension ClosureInitialization where Self: UIView {

    init(_ configurationClosure: (Self) -> ()) {
        self.init(frame: .zero)
        configurationClosure(self)
    }
}

extension UIView: ClosureInitialization {}

var myLabel = UILabel {
    $0.text = "Label"
    $0.textColor = .black
}
```